# How do I prevent video playback when <video> was tapped during scrolling with overflow-scrolling:touch on?

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, vertical-scrolling

I use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` within an overflowing div container. Within this container I have a `<video>` element.

On iPhone, when I scroll down, I usually tap the scrolling view in order to stop it. This is usually no problem, even if I hit a link. The browser understands that I wanted to stop scrolling and not open the link.

The problem here is if I hit the play button of the video accidentally, the playback starts which is not intended. How can I fix this?

**Demo** (open on iPhone!): http://www.timo-ernst.net/misc/scrollvideo/

**Full source code:**

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title>Scroll video test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <style>
      *{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
      }
      html, body{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .scrollarea{
        height:100%;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        overflow-y:scroll;
      }

      #video{
        width: 100%;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="scrollarea">
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      scroll down for video<br>
      <video id="video" src="http://video.golem.de/download/15799?q=medium&rd=rlmob_nojs" controls="1" poster="http://video.golem.de/teaser/1/1/15799/medium-480-regatta-snap.jpg" x-webkit-airplay="allow" preload="none"></video>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video<br>
      scroll up for video
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Everything seems to be working fine for me. iPhone 6 on iOS 8.x. It was actually a little difficult for me to get the video to start playing even when I had the intention of having it play.

Comment: @JesseDockett Nope, i scroll down, let the momentum keep scrolling, then hit the play button while momentum ist still doing its thing then suddenly video starts playing. Using iPhone5 with iOS8.

Comment: @JesseDockett It's possible that the video actually started buffering through your click event but took a while until it started playing. Try getting that video in your cache and try again.

Comment: I went back and tried again. If i start the video player and then dismiss it by hitting "Done" and then scroll to the top and try again I can get it to play again by following the steps that you're describing. I'm not sure if there is a way around that. Kind of a very specific error. If it's absolutely a must have, I would suggest setting "pointer-events" to "none" and then running a simple script that checks the scrolling of the page and turns "pointer-events" to "auto" for the player after scrolling has stopped.